# ASP.Net Core Docker error: Sqlcmd: Error: Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: docker

Following the [Getting Started template tutorial](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html), I have run into this particular error (right in the end, when the containers are starting):

[image: error message]

When I get docker logs for the first unhealthy container I get this:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. .
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
Where-Object : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\StartInit.ps1:34 char:29
+ ...                Where-Object { $serverDatabases.Contains($_.BaseName)}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Where-Object], RuntimeExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands
   .WhereObjectCommand
```

I am stuck, searched all over the web, but cannot find a solution. Help appreciated.

Comment: Is this happening in your local environment?

Comment: Yes, Im running docker on my on machine

Comment: I recently ran into this issue and believe it was caused by my corporate VPN. Once I disconnected from VPN, things started working again.

Comment: @tpower stuck on the same error, have you found the answer for this?